# Azure SQL Database in auto-failover configuration ignores requests to failover

Tags: sql, azure, failover

I was testing new auto-failover group feature of Azure SQL Database. Setting up was easy, using new endpoints and connection strings seems to be pretty straightforward too. BUT, when I try to manually force failover to the secondary database using portal, nothing happens. My requests to failover appear in the Activity Log, but nothing happens after that. The database never switches to the secondary location. 
Does anyone else experience something like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your servers into auto-failover group, "Forced Failover" menu item in "Geo Replication" screen becomes useless without any warning. You should instead go to Server -> Failover Groups, select your failover group and use Failover or Force Failover from there.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this. Since all the actions related failover group(not just geo-replication) are under Microsoft.Sql/**servers**/failoverGroups/*, so that the actions should be performed via Server -> Failover Groups.

Also, SQL server contributor is able to do failover as above, but SQL DB contributor is not.

Some [network security settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview#failover-groups-and-network-security) on sql server might also block the failover.